# Do I need a comma in "He bought a pen and an eraser(,) and went home."?

Tags: commas

> He bought a pen and an eraser(,) and went home.

Based on the rules I'm aware of, I don't need the comma.

However, when perceiving the sentence as a reader, I'd fall into something like

> action, enumeration, 1, 2, 3, ... wait the third one is not enumeration, it's another action.

When having the comma, it'd be something like

> action, enumeration, 1, 2, there's something different ahead, it's another action.

Is the comma ungrammatical, or is it an optional comma, like an Oxford one?

Comment: The comma would be ungrammatical.  If you want to be clear that this is not a list, you could say, "and **then** went home** to emphasize that the going home occurs after the buying of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commas are there to make your reader's life easier and avoid ambiguities.  They also help the reader to find the intonation pattern that the writer has in their head.

In this example there is a strong case for including the comma.

You would say it as "He bought a pen and an eraser (falling intonation, slight pause) and went home (rising then falling intonation)"

You can help the reader to find this by including a comma.

You can also slightly re-write

> He bought a pen and an eraser, then he went home.

Which is hardly any longer, and is clearer to read.